# Rename IXMLDOMNode

Tags: c++, xml, com, msxml

I am trying to rename a `IXMLDOMNode`, which is not possible the "retail" way.
I have been searching this for quite a while and been trying various solutions.
I cannot seem to figure out how I can properly rename a Node.

I tried to replace it directly `->replaceChild(...)` which results in having no parent, childs and sibling nodes.

I tried to simply remove it `->removeChild(...)` and add the new item before the first ones sibling `->insertBefore(...)` which also results in having no parent, childs and sibling nodes.

I do iterate through childs and attributes and add them to their new owners, but nothing seems to work.

**Q: Is there any way I can 'simply' rename a node ?**

Comment: Would you consider using [XSLT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762799(v=vs.85).aspx) to do the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: @selbie I could consider using this, if I would have any idea (even after reading through it) how I should use it & how it works...

Comment: An XSLT file is an XML file that specifies how to transform another XML file into something else - typically to another schema or HTML. You write a transform XSLT file.  Then you invoke the transform on the XML doc. You probably just need only a few rules to rename the node in question. You'll have to learn XSLT (Google it), but the link above shows how to invoke the transform in code.

Comment: I suggested this because doing anything XML in C/C++ with MSXML usually results in a lot of spaghetti code that should be otherwise simple in a scripting language.